# Conditionally rendering <f:selectItem> inside <c:if>,<ui:fragment>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to display **No Jurisdiction to add** in the Jurisdiction dropdown when the given condition satisfies.[condition:When there is no Jurisdiction available,it should display the above text in dropdown.If there are jurisdictions available,the above text should not be displayed].And I dont want to make it disabled.

[image]

The problem i am facing is whether it does or does not displays **No Jurisdiction to add** irrespective of the condition provided.

[image]

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="JurisdictionName"
 value="#{ApplicationManagedBean62.saveRequestMap['Jurisdiction']}"
 <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="" />
    <c:if test="#{empty ApplicationManagedBean62.knowledgeValueMap['Object::AddJurisdictionStatelist']}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="No Jurisdiction to add" itemValue=""  />
    </c:if>
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{ApplicationManagedBean62.knowledgeValueMap['Object::AddJurisdictionStatelist']}"
        var="Jurisdiction"
        itemLabel="#{Jurisdiction['StateRegionCode']}"
        itemValue="#{Jurisdiction['StateRegionCode']}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

I also tried,

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{empty ApplicationManagedBean62.knowledgeValueMap['Object::AddJurisdictionStatelist']}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="No Jurisdiction to add" itemValue="No Jurisdiction to add"  />
</ui:fragment>
```

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it like that you have 2 choices.

1. Use `itemDisabled="true"` or `noSelectionOption="true"` on items you don't want selectable and they will be greyed out. See: https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/5.0/vdldoc/f/selectItem.html
2. Generate your selectItems server side and filter out the ones you know should not be there like this...

```xml
<f:selectItems value="#{myBean.jurisdictions}" var="type" itemLabel="#{type.displayText}" itemValue="#{type}" />
```